# Ideas for branching strategy for a web application?

Tags: version-control

I'm interested in your thoughts on my branching strategy for our web application. In particular, I want to know if I have accommodated the business needs for different execution environments.

Here's the situation:

- Our software is a web application
- Our release cadence anticipates periodic (say, quarterly) releases
- Our customers generally only need to use the latest released version of the software
- Some customers need to use a pre-release ("UAT") version to evaluate new features

With this in mind, I have proposed a 4-branch system:

- Dev - For ongoing latest development
- QA - For internal QA needs
- UAT - For pre-release testing
- Production - For customers

Merges will take place in the following manner:

- Changes to the QA branch will be made by merging FROM Trunk
- Changes to the UAT branch will be made by merging FROM UAT
- Changes to the Production branch will be made by merging FROM Production

Deployments will take place in the following manner:

- Builds from the Dev branch will be deployed to the Dev environment
- Builds from the QA branch will be deployed to the QA environment
- Builds from the UAT branch will be deployed to the UAT environment
- Builds from the Production branch will be deployed to the Production environment

So, what do you think? Am I vaguely on track?

Comment: Interesting, but perhaps better suited to programmers: there is no tidy objectively answerable programming question here. (Oh, and you are using a *good* VCS, right? ;-)

Comment: @pst How do I migrate a question to a different forum? And yeah, our VCS is decent anyway (we're using TFS, which at a minimum at least handles branching ok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We basically use that strategy.  A branch per environment.

Sometimes we make a service pack branch for any major issues that we would eventually dead end.

There is a TFS branching strategy guide on codeplex.

http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good. 
But from my past experience the only suggestions I would have is to make the repository version (1.1.1_C0, 1.1.0_B0 or 1.0.0_A0 ) dependent rather than Environment(Dev, UAT, PROD)
dependent in branches. This does work well or us.
We tag each version based on which phase of development the code is in.